# Como asignar un array de una cookie a un int[] C#

Tags: c#, cookies

Desde una página `html` creé una `cookie`.

```
//document.cookie="Arrayids="+ JSON.stringify(arreglochecks);

     public ActionResult UnController(FormCollection objetos)
           {
       var array=ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["Arrayids"];
         int[,] intArray = new int[array.GetLength(0), array.GetLength(1)];
   //aquí pretendo recuperar valor en mi variable 'intArray'
 ..
 }
```

Comment: Ojo que los cookies son para guardar poca información. Tienen límites.

Comment: Para que usaras ese array, porque no usas una variable de session o del lado del cliente, depende de su uso.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo Juan Carlos Guibovich, el uso de cookies es para almacenar ids que el usuario checkea en un webgrid(en lado cliente),pero luego requiero recuperar estos valores para filtrar en una lista de pedido; osea que lo mando a un controller donde verá datos únicamente de esos productos, por lo que intentaba algo como:

```
db.Almacen.Where(b => b.Identificador).Contains(Convert.ToInt64(array)).ToList();
```

donde array es construido de la sig forma:

```
string[] array = arrcokies.Split(separator, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Al final la solución pasó por meter los números en una lista

```
  for (int i=0; i<array.Length; i++)
{
 lstids.Add(Convert.toInt32(array[i]));
}
```

//Por último filtrar con LINQ 
lstids.Contains((int)itm.Identificador)